# Golang library for implementation of RTSP client

Tags: go, client, rtsp, capture

I have an infrastructure which contains above seven dozens IP-cameras connected to the video server over Internet. This structure is geo-distributed and models of cameras are diffrents. Also methods of connections of cameras to Internet are differents. At my conclusion... it's a zoo :) Unfortunately software for fetching of video stream has no special features for monitoring of cameras state (this software is proprietary & commercial and no flexibility). By this reason I want to write and very easy monitoring tool for checking of state of health cameras. I have a little bit expirience in Golang and I found few libraries.
Can you advise the best library for working with RTSP at Go? My tasks are very simple: checking for connection by TCP to the camera, checking of connection by RTSP and fetching the one frame from the stream. Maybe you know the library where enumerated features are available out-of-box?

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing some RTSP + Golang research myself and there are a couple projects you might be interested in. Although I don't think any one has all the features you are asking for. You could definitely take a look at the code and come up with your own custom solution.

If you would like to build a custom tool to check rtsp streams I would definitely like to join you! I have a couple ip cameras I've been meaning to get working and I'm decent at Golang so it might just work out. Let me know!

Check out:

Cameradar - RTSP stream access tool
https://github.com/Ullaakut/cameradar

> It is actually a program for attacking rtsp stream cameras, but it seems to have an interface for connecting to cameras just fine.

Videostreamer - RTSP stream to MP4
https://github.com/horgh/videostreamer

> Seems like a decent program for remuxing a rtsp stream. Might have some code you like as well.